# VSCode API: Set editor to ReadOnly mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The Monaco editor has a way to disable edits via a readOnly setting (https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/54), which is quite useful in an extension that steps through code, aids code review, etc.

Is there a similar setting for this in VSCode API?

Comment: Isn't that what your version control system is for? If you make accidental edits, you can still revert. I hardly see the use case for this.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/4873

Comment: files that are semantically 'readonly' should notify/prevent the user from editing them (esp if you are editing the .js derived from a .ts; it wastes your time)

See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161715

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222660/836330 for an early implementation of the ability to set an editor as read-only.  (Thanks @JackPunt)

Answer (score 0):

See more at  [Readonly Mode in v1.79 Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_readonly-mode)

Here are the new commands you are looking for:

- `Set Active Editor Readonly in Session`: mark active editor readonly
- `Set Active Editor Writeable in Session`: mark active editor writeable
- `Toggle Active Editor Readonly in Session`: toggle between readonly and writeable
- `Clear (or may be named Reset) Active Editor Readonly in Session`: clear/reset the session state

Demo at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222660/836330