# VSCode how to disable typing on editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually open a tab as a reference, but sometimes I accidentally type on it, how to lock that tab to prevent typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a feature implemented I am aware of, but I recommend checking this thread out:

[How to open a file in read-only mode with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184982/how-to-open-a-file-in-read-only-mode-with-vs-code)